# AngularJs (oi.multiselect) only post object name not the array

Tags: php, angularjs

I have added a autocomplete field to a form on my website, but when posting my data, the field posts the hole field object, not just the field name. Example of post object:

```
name: "bla bla"
ordre_confirmed: "No"
paid: "No"
phone: "12345678"
product: ""
start_date: ""
status: "Active"
study: ""
subjects: ""
teacher: {id: 963, status: "Active", name: "name", adress: "", zip: ,…}
text_message: ""
transport: 100
zip: 2000
```

But I only need to post "teacher.name" to the form, the AngularJS directive i use to create my autocomplete field is called "oi.multiselect", it can be found here: https://github.com/tamtakoe/oi.multiselect.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, since `oi-multiselect`'s API is the same as for simple `select`:

```
<oi-multiselect
  ng-options="item.teacher.name for item in items"
  ng-model="selectedItems"
  multiple
  placeholder="Select"
></oi-multiselect>
```

Where `items` is an array with your entities, `selectedItems` are the selected items. I can't provide a demo right now, unfortunately, please give it a try.

Comment: It still seems to post an array of data instead of the teacher name, thanks Ilya

Comment: @MikkelEmilLindblom Try this query - `ng-options="item.teacher.name as item.teacher.name for item in items"`. This seems a bit strange, but if name is unique, then OK, I guess. Here is little [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vhecyh67/), although it's with plain `ngOptions`, that shouldn't be a problem.